# Translating nginx rewrite rule to Windows web.config

Tags: windows, iis, nginx, web-config, url-rewriting

Someone shared useful rewrite rule for Korean CMS that I am using but I am using windows server.
Could anyone kindly change following rules to Windows server Web.config for IIS 7.5 rewrite rule?

I thank you for your kind help!
PS. Even if .htaccess file would work too as I can import the .htacess rule to IIS. :)

```
# reserve XE Layout Template Source File (*.html)
rewrite ^/(layouts|m.layouts)/(.+)/(.+)\.html$ /index.php last;

# conf, query, schema
rewrite ^/(modules|addons|widgets)/(.+)/(conf|queries|schemas)/(.+)\.xml$ /index.php last;

# static files
if (!-f $request_filename) {
rewrite ^/(.+)/files/(member_extra_info|attach|cache|faceOff)/(.*) /files/$2/$3 last;
}
if (!-f $request_filename) {
rewrite ^/(.+)/(files|modules|widgets|widgetstyles|layouts|m.layouts|addons)/(.*) /$2/$3 last;
}

# rss , blogAPI
rewrite ^/(rss|atom)$ /index.php?module=rss&act=$1 last;
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(rss|atom|api)$ /index.php?mid=$1&act=$2 last;
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(rss|atom|api)$ /index.php?vid=$1&mid=$2&act=$3 last;

# trackback
rewrite ^/([0-9]+)/(.+)/trackback$ /index.php?document_srl=$1&key=$2&act=trackback last;
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+)/trackback$ /index.php?mid=$1&document_srl=$2&key=$3&act=trackback last;
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+)/trackback$ /index.php?vid=$1&document_srl=$2&key=$3&act=trackback last;
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+)/trackback$ /index.php?vid=$1&mid=$2&document_srl=$3&key=$4&act=trackback last;

# administrator page
rewrite ^/admin/?$ /index.php?module=admin last;

# document permanent link
rewrite ^/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?document_srl=$1 last;

# mid link
if (!-d $request_filename) {
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ /index.php?mid=$1 last;
}

# mid + document link
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?mid=$1&document_srl=$2 last;

# vid + mid link
if (!-d $request_filename) {
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ /index.php?vid=$1&mid=$2 last;
}

# vid + mid + document link
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?vid=$1&mid=$2&document_srl=$3 last;

# mid + entry title
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/entry/(.+)$ /index.php?mid=$1&entry=$2 last;

# vid + mid + entry title
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/entry/(.+)$ ^/index.php?vid=$1&mid=$2&entry=$3 last;

# shop + vid / [category|product] / identifier
if (!-f $request_filename) {
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)$ /index.php?act=route&vid=$1&type=$2&identifier=$3 last;
}
```